# Movie from 2005-2014 about a girl student who travels to alternate universes for a relationship

Tags: story-identification, movie, parallel-universe

I'm looking for а film, watched in 2016, where a boy dumps his girlfriend and she -- in a university with a spinning top (spinning, twisting and falling asleep or faiting) and a dark-skinned professor -- travels to alternate universes for a relationship.

She builds different versions of her ex-boyfriend (more alternative, unhappy love story), but returns to where she left and takes stock of the experience, understanding that this is the best solution.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the main character?

Comment: Also, what did you mean by _"in University with a spinning top (spinning and falling asleep)"_...?

Comment: https://irememberthismovie.com/the-girl-travels-through-parallel-universes/ - This person looking for the same movie (alas unsolved).

Comment: @Valorum - Hm, judging by the phrasing of that other question, it sounds like the device used to enter other universes resembles a spinning top.

Comment: @LogicDictates - I'm wondering if OP posted both questions.

Comment: @Valorum - The avatar of the OP here appears in the comments beneath the other question.

Comment: @LogicDictates  Thank you! I think the girl was a brunette...

Comment: @Valorum top like in the movie "Inception". 2010 - she twisted, fell asleep (or fainted) and moved around

Answer (score 4):

*Another You* (2017).
Brief summary from [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/another_you_2016):

> An ambitious science student finds true love and refuses to let it go, which creates an unhealthy obsession with her boyfriend. Using a scientific breakthrough, she finds a way to explore her past mistakes and protect her fixation at all costs.

The plot points are scattered among several reviews.

- [Review #1](https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/review/B06XXNTCY8/R29AW5KME3DF8R) has the girl being dumped:

> there was something odd about a movie that has a love interest turning a "just not that into you" anymore cold shoulder on Ksenia Solo- of all the ridiculously gorgeous women in the world!

- [Review #2](https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/review/B06XXNTCY8/R3NYFY40GMHRJW) and [review #3](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw3741910/) have the girl "building" her boyfriend through a scientific breakthrough (or I guess so, since they mention undesired versions of him):

> I like the aspect that compares what the character is doing to a drug addiction, and it basically portrays her as junkie. [...] I did understand her pain which is more than I could say for a lot of movies. It explores very well the pain of constantly turning over and over in our minds what we did wrong and how we could change it, sometimes to our own peril.

> Don't know if it was intended to show the nature of identity on multiple timelines (?) but they seemed more like subjects in an experiment. The parts where Sydney attempts to correct the undesired timeline resulted in some intriguing alt. timelines. In my opinion, the ending was conclusive. She made a decision leading to an untampered timeline where the future is uncertain.

Finally, the trailer (which I only found  [on IMDb so far](https://www.imdb.com/video/vi3683957017/?playlistId=tt2926924), hence not linkable inline) has a dark-skinned teacher.

**Not** to be confused with:

- [*I Am Another You*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6098544/), which is also from 2017, but is completely unrelated (and messes with searches for the former);
- [*Another Version Of You*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5168238/), also known as *Other Versions Of You*, from 2018, which **does** have a similar plot but with the genders reversed;
- [*Another You*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_You) from 1991, which is also completely unrelated except for the title.

---

Found with the Google query `Sci-Fi girl travels alternate universes for boyfriend  site:imdb.com/title`. (But then had to filter out all the results pertaining unrelated movies above to confirm it!)